# 2GP Managed package Custom Field visibility

Tags: metadata-api, 2gp

I've a managed 2GP with some CustomObjects. I set their visibility to public like this:

```
<visibility>Public</visibility>
```

I've also a CustomField on the existing Opportunity object. But the problem that I have, is that the field is always hidden for all the users when I install the package...

Is there a way to make its visibility public like I do for my CustomObjects?

Thanks!

Comment: You simply need to ensure that at least read permission is granted to those users who need it (ideally via perm sets, or at least through profiles). This `visibility` property is nothing to do with permissions.

Comment: @PhilW: Is there a way to do this automatically on package installation?

Comment: I seriously recommend against making the field visible to all users automatically. Instead, include perm set(s) that define the required permissions for your managed package functionality. Then document which one(s) to assign after the installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visibility is subjective in the way you wrote your post. You mean visible on a layout? Or accessible by the user in the database? Regardless, you have two options here:

1. If you are talking about the layout visibility, that's not how this works. You should make the field visible giving permissions to the user through their profile (like a standard user or admin profile) or permission set. Layouts are not editable by packages. You can create a page layout that is installed alongside your package, but the admin should choose whether to use that layout instead of the one they have set up. In this regard, you are better off instructing the subscriber to add your field to their layout instead.
2. On accessibility by the user, you should make this field accessible with permissions (profiles or permission sets). It is up to the subscriber to grant access to your package content through those profiles or permission sets when they install the package.

Comment: I'm able to edit the default Opportunity layout to add my field to it. I understand that the user can use a different layout and that he may have to edit it to add my Custom Field. 
The problem, is that when I click on "View Field Accessibility" in the Object Manager, my Custom field is hidden for all the profiles. If I make it visible, it's working as expected. But if I understand correctly, the only way to to this is to pack a Profile or a PermissionSet with my package and to tell the users to add it to their user, right? I can't do it automatically?

Comment: Your package can't edit permissions for profiles and permission sets that already exist in the subscriber's organization. Hence why you should create a permission set with that visibility or a profile with it (and then let the admin user decide if they want to merge those permissions with an existing profile with their org or not - but I highly discourage this option as Salesforce is moving permissioning to permission sets instead of profiles on the long run).

Comment: Also: permission sets are internal records. If you have some kind of scenario where you want all users in the subscriber org to have access to a certain permission, you could have your package implement a post-install script that creates the PermissionSetAssignment record for all users in the target org. The caveat here is that you have no way to know which users should get the permission or not - so this is discouraged as well.